# Header loses uper case in rmarkdown + tufte

Tags: yaml, latex, r-markdown

[image]I'm trying to keep the uppercase part of the title in the page-headers; it shows ok in the title page, so I'm looking for a way to pass text as it is from the yaml header to the page headers, I've seen examples with plain latex where passing strings as they are is the default behavior, so I guess it is somewhere in the chain yaml-rmarkdown-tufte; my yaml header is the following, it renders "guatemala", so I'd like to have the capital G here.

[link to log file](https://gitlab.com/datamarindo/pandoc/-/blob/master/guatemala.log)

```yaml
---
title: "Intercambio de experiencias en restauración de manglar: Guatemala"
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  tufte::tufte_html: 
    self_contained: yes
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
author: "Pronatura Veracruz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
link-citations: yes
bibliography: biblio.bib
lang: es
urlcolor: blue
linkcolor: blue
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{lancha.jpg}\LARGE\\}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
  - \usepackage{tocloft}
---
```

Comment: Can you show 1) a screenshot of  your output and 2) your latex .log file? I not only get an uppercase G, but the whole header is in all caps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G6Vk.png

Comment: Sure, I attached the log file and the picture of the header, I wouldn't mind if header looked like the one you show

Comment: The problem might be that you don't have the `soul` latex package installed.

Comment: Does it work if you use the `nols` documentclass option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Install the `soul` latex package

#### Long version

The tufte class does not use the usual small caps from latex, but redefines them. To do this, it normally uses the `soul` package.

However the soul package is only an optional dependency of the tufte class. If it is installed, it will be used, if it is not installed, you can still compile the document, you just don't get all the features.

Now the unfortunate series of events continues. You are using tinytex, which by default is missing nearly all packages -- amongst the missing packages is the soul package. And because the soul package is only an optional dependency, tinytex's automatic installation of missing packages does not kick in.

To solve this, either manually install `soul` or (better) use a complete texlive installation instead of tinytex, so you'll never again have problems with missing packages.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, can this `soul` package help in making title case?

Comment: @ElioDiaz Not directly. Making the header all caps is a design decision of the tufte class. You would have to overwrite the settings made by the class.